# Server side end point equivalents for ajax for Java EE, ASP.NET and LAMP

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jakarta-ee, lamp

When an AJAX call from the client side hits the server url, data of the type JSON, XML or CSV is exchanged with the browser.

What are the various alternatives for the server side end point for each of the following technologies for the AJAX url call (i.e. `xmlhttprequestobj.open(TARGETURL)`)

1) ASP.NET (excluding AJAX Toolkit)

TARGETURL can be ASMX, WCF services, ASP .NET page serving the content

Is there any other way?
What is the standard way?

2.) For Java EE the target URL should be a servlet?
What is the standard here?

3.) How does it work for the LAMP stack and PHP?
What is the standard here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java EE, Servlets can indeed be used. However, if you're looking at a more of less independent client application that does (AJAX) calls to server-side services, then `JAX-RS` is much more typical. JAX-RS' main function is to provide RESTFull web-services.

If you're looking at web pages that are more integrated with the server application, then `JSF` has first class support for processing AJAX calls as well. JSF's main function is to provide a component based MVC web framework.

The big difference is that with JAX-RS, you'll be making explicit calls using some URL pattern from your application and will manually process the data it returns (which can be in JSON or XML, but is rarely CSV).

With JSF the AJAX machinery is more a behind the scenes kind of thing for the average application developer. You put some component on your page, specify bindings to some `backing bean`, and at run-time AJAX interactions will take place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example mod_rewrite in apache with php application and then your url can be for example yourapp.com/user/seahorse and this can be mapped by your application to whatever.php script. So url needn't be exactly mapped to some code unit.

If you are using LAMP, then you probably create new virtual host in apache config files, that is mapped to some domain (for example yourblog.com). And then if apache gets request to this domain, then it see to home directory of this app and try find appropriate script. 
    yourblog.com/user/whatever.php -> yourblog directory -> user directory - whatever.php
    script.
Or you can put special file .htaccess to home directory of your app and in this file put some rewrite condition, for example all requests to index.php script.